# Pushforward definition question.

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

Using notations from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)). If $\phi: M \to N$ is a smooth map with derivative map $d\phi_x: T_xM \to T_{\phi(x)}N.$

The pushforward of $X$ by $\phi$ is $$d\phi_x(X)f := X(f\circ \phi).  \tag{1}$$

where $f \in C^\infty(N).$

Now I know $X \in T_pM$ as a tangent vector is a derivation acting on functions in $C^\infty(M).$ So as wikipedia says, $d\phi_x(X)$ is a tangent vector in $T_{\phi(x)}N$ derivation acting on functions in $C^\infty(N)$. Then isn't $X$ still acting on functions on $M$ in this definition in equation (1) ? All this defintion did was pullback $f$, but $X$ is still a tangent vector on $T_xM$ not $T_{\phi(x)}N.$

Also on page 53 of John Lee's Intro to Smooth manifold book, where he denotes $\nu = X$ here in wiki notation. He notes $\nu \in T_pM$ but calls it a derivation at $F(p)$ ($F$ is our $\phi$ here).

Comment: I guess you must be looking at page 55 of my book, not page 53. Look carefully at what I wrote: it says that if $v\in T_pM$, then $dF_p(v)$ is a derivation at $F(p)$, not that $v$ is a derivation at $F(p)$. (BTW, the symbol $v$ there is the italic letter $v$, not the Greek letter nu.)

Comment: @JackLee well i did not expect the author to reply! You are right, i misread that line. That removes one confusion.

Answer (score 4):

In your equation $(1)$, $f$ is not a function on $M$ but a function on $N$. So the vector $Y = d\phi_x(X)$, which we want to be an element of $T_{\phi(x)} N$, acts on functions on $N$.

Now, how you **define** the action of the vector $Y$ is a completely different business. Yes, you **use** the action of $X$ on functions on $M$ to define the action of $Y$: you take the function $f: N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and transport it to a function $f \circ \phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb R$, then apply $X$ to **this** (new) function. But the fact remains that in this way, your $Y$ takes functions **on $N$** and returns numbers, and it does so as a derivation.

To be more specific, $Y = d\phi_x(X)$ is a derivation at $\phi(x)$. What this means is that it takes equivalence classes of functions from an open neighborhood of $\phi(x)$ to $\mathbb R$, where two functions are equivalent iff they are equal on an open neighborhood of $\phi(x)$, and returns a real number for each such equivalence class, and it does this respecting the Leibniz rule.

Let $[f]$ be such an equivalence class, with a representative $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $\phi(x) \in U$ and $U \subset N$ is open.
To specify the vector $Y \in T_{\phi(x)} N$, it's enough to specify its values on every such class $[f]$, and then to check that the specification you give satisfies the Leibniz rule - this is just because that is what a vector at $\phi(x)$ is, it is precisely such a specification of some values for each class $[f]$.

So we specify the values as such: we put by definition $Y([f]):= X([g])$, where $g$ is the function $g: \phi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $g := f \circ \phi\vert_{\phi^{-1}(U)}$ where since $\phi(x) \in U$ and $\phi$ is continuous, $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, so $g$ does indeed define a class like the ones $X$ takes as argument.

Now it's immediate to check that since $X([g])$ doesn't depend on the representative we choose for the class $[g]$, neither does $Y$ depend on the representative $f$. Indeed, suppose $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $f_1: V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are two functions such that $\phi(x) \in W \subset U \cap V$ where $W$ is an open set with $f|_W = f_1|_W$. Then $f_1 \circ \phi|_{\phi^{-1}(V)}$ coincides with $f \circ \phi|_{\phi^{-1}(U)}$ on $\phi^{-1}(W)$, so, since $X$ is a vector, $X([f_1 \circ \phi|_{\phi^{-1}(V)}]) = X( [f \circ \phi|_{\phi^{-1}(U)}] )$.

One can also easily see that $Y$ satisfies the Leibniz rule, using that $X$ satisfies it: for two classes of functions $[f], [g]$ at $\phi(x)$ we have that
\begin{align*}
Y([f]\cdot[g]) &\stackrel{\textrm{ def $[f]\cdot[g]$}}{=} Y([fg]) 
\stackrel{\textrm{ def $Y$}}{=} X ([(fg)\circ\phi)]) \\
&=X([ (f \circ \phi) \cdot (g \circ \phi) ]) \\
&=(f \circ \phi)(x) X([g\circ \phi]) + (g \circ \phi)(x) X([f\circ \phi])
\textrm{ (bcs. $X$ satisfies Leibniz) } \\
&=f(\phi(x)) Y([g]) + g(\phi(x)) Y([f])
\end{align*}

But the condition
$$
Y([f]\cdot[g]) = f(\phi(x)) Y([g]) + g(\phi(x)) Y([f])
$$
is precisely what it means for $Y$ to satisfy the Leibniz rule at $\phi(x)$.

So $Y$ is a vector at $\phi(x)$ by definition: it maps equivalence classes of local functions at $\phi(x)$ on $N$ to numbers satisfying the Leibniz rule, and this is by definition what a vector does.

Comment: "your $Y$ takes functions **on** N", you mean the $f$ in $X(f\circ \phi)$? That's why we define $d\phi(X)f$ this way? Even though $X$ is derivation at $x$? Because Lee calls $X$ a derivation at the targeted point $\phi(x)$ instead and that confuses me.

Comment: @Lemon I've added some explanations, I hope they help

Comment: "we put by definition ([]):=([])" this is actually my original question. WHy is this the definition? If we go back to my original notation. $X$ is passed by the derivative map of $\phi$, but the RHS is still using $X$ and I don't see where the dependence of the derivative of $\phi$ on the right hand side. Where is the smoothness of $\phi$ occuring on the RHS?

Comment: $\phi$ must be smooth because $X$ must take as arguments smooth functions and if $f$ is smooth, then $f \circ \phi$ is smooth.

Comment: As to the dependence on the derivative of $\phi$, what we are actually doing here is defining the derivative in a coordinate-free way. It's a natural def.; think that for $\phi: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$, in a basis for $T_x \mathbb R^n$, $\{ \partial/\partial x_i \}$, the matrix of $d_x \phi$ is given by $[ \partial \phi_j / \partial x_i ]_{i,j}$, but the column vector $(\partial \phi_j / \partial x_i )_j$ is actually $d_x \phi( \partial/ \partial x_i)$ in the new definition